# Possible to make a flow that forms horseshoes on a 2-dimensional manifold?

Tags: dynamical-systems, examples-counterexamples, chaos-theory

It it possible to have a flow $\phi(t,x)$ on a 2-dimensional manifold where for some $t > 0$, the map

$g(x) := \phi(t,x)$

creates a horseshoe?

By $\phi(t,x)$ I mean the solution to the ODE defining the flow on the manifold at time $t$, from starting time $0$ and starting position $x$.

There seem to be a number of iterated maps, like the toral automorphisms, or of course the standard horseshoe map, which create horseshoes.  But they don't seem like they can be realized as time-1 maps of flows, and I'm wondering if there's a general fact that this can't be done.  Basically any references or insight about when a map can be realized as a flow in general would be really helpful as well.

Thanks.

Comment: Of course it is possible (if you have 3+ dimensions in autonomous ODE, and then take a time-1 map or some Poincare section), the whole theory of chaos nonlinear dynamics rests on this fact.

Answer (score 0):

Your $g(x)$ is strangely defined (as the expression on the right-hand side is $t$-dependent) but I think I get the problem. So imagine you have a smale horsehoe generated by a 2 dimensional discrete dynamical system (by which I mean you have the unstable manifold intersecting the stable manifold in such a way that you get a smale horseshoe). How do you see this back in an ODE. You actually cannot have this in a 2 dimensional ODE you really need a third dimension since solution curves cannot self-intersect. To view this in 3 dimensions imagine that the 2-dimensional discrete dynamical systems corresponds to the poincare map associated to the 3 dimensional ODE.  If anything needs more explanation let met know.

Comment: I'm just asking about the 2D case, and why/if that cannot happen in 2D.  I can see that it happens in 3D, and for, say, the horseshoe map on the unit cube in $\mathbb{R}^2$ I can sort of see how you might make anargument based on solution curves not intersecting, but I can't seem to make it precise, and whether or not you can make some specially designed 2D manifold to have the solution curves not intersect I'm not really sure.  If there are any sources that prove this cannot happen and go through the details I would be interested.

Comment: We are talking here about the chaos generating horseshoe right? Where you consider the intersection of the forward and backward iterates of the horseshoe. The forward and backward flow of the 2-d ODE self-intersect by construction. For an ODE this can only be the case if there is a connecting path between two invariant sets (Self intersection yield invariant sets). In the limit the horseshoe must then have uncountably many disjoint invariant sets. Q: Why is this not possible?